# Java Regex with OR condition to Split String

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I need to build a regex to Split my string starting with a number or LM(exact match as it is a special case)

```
For example - 
Input : 1LM355PL6R5L8
Output : [1,LM,3,5,5PL,6R,5L,8]

Input : 349AB8LM7Y4II
Output : [3,4,9AB,8,LM,7Y,4II]
```

For numbers, i've build this regex `(?<!^)(?=\\d)` and it seems to be working fine.
Now i'm confused how to add this exact match of 'LM'. It can be at any position

```
List<String> diff = Arrays.asList(inputString.split("(?<!^)(?=\\d)"));
```

Actual Output with above code

```
Output : [1LM,3,5,5PL,6R,5L,8]
    
Output : [3,4,9AB,8LM,7Y,4II]
```

I'm trying to put an OR condition in my regex and make strict match for LM but not getting correct results from it.

```
List<String> diff = Arrays.asList(inputString.split("(?<!^)(?=\\d)|('LM')"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The or part with `|` should be put inside the lookahead and there should not be quotes around `LM`.

```java
inputString.split("(?<!^)(?=\\d|LM)")
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZYxBS8NAEIXv@RVjTruCC0UiQltL7xsQe7QKY5OGiZtk2ZkEi/a3xw0NKvguA@/75tU44E1dvI8jNb4LAnUsTC/kzPUy@deFsio/JuL7N0cHODhkhhyphc8EYuaeBSWeoaMCmkjVTgK11fMLYKhYz/KUAQNQ63u5GLCGdGHz2yx7tHdPmb1Plz@qJZbVRXuAgo7HKG9DwBMb5AmqP0OGvSNRqdqsrl612qz3@@LL5jrV@ndxd2IpG9P1Ynx8EteqaXc2zsl5HL8B)

Comment: Just one more thing, if i also need to add LM-6 as my special case, how should i do it. adding '|LM-6'  splits it to ['LM-', 6]

Comment: @jasmeet You could do something like this: `"(?<!^)(?=((?<!LM-)|(?!6))\\d|LM)"`